# Efficient method to load/get and assign multiple custom options/attributes from quote item?

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, quote, custom-attributes

Is there a more efficient way to load and assign quote item custom options/attributes?

This is code in my Observer:

```
public function MyFunction(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
$QuoteObject = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        foreach ($QuoteObject->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
            $custom_attr1 = $item->getData('custom1');
            $custom_attr2 = $item->getData('custom2');
            $custom_attr3 = $item->getData('custom3');
            $custom_attr4 = $item->getData('custom4');
            $custom_attr5 = $item->getData('custom5');
           //do other stuff here
        }
  //do some other stuff here
}
```

Comment: which observer you are using ?

Comment: @Pawan Am using the **sales_order_place_after** event in custom observer.                                             
Want to know if there is some way to 'get' all the data using an array. Eg to reduce database requests. Or if my existing method is best method.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about efficient but you can use more **elegant** way for above code:

You can use `$observer` object for get `Quote`.

```
public function MyFunction(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
$QuoteObject = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
        foreach ($QuoteObject->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
            $custom_attr1 = $item->getData('custom1');
            $custom_attr2 = $item->getData('custom2');
            $custom_attr3 = $item->getData('custom3');
            $custom_attr4 = $item->getData('custom4');
            $custom_attr5 = $item->getData('custom5');
           //do other stuff here
        }
  //do some other stuff here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That's a small but welcome improvement.

Comment: welcome @Dan, I think above is the best option, did you find other ?

Comment: Unfortunately using `$QuoteObject = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();`
 didn't work for me (unknown reasons, no exceptions or log errors, but the order process died using this). 
So I have stuck with using `$QuoteObject = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();`  which works successfully.
  But thanks for suggesting.

Comment: you can use `checkout_submit_all_after` event.

Comment: Ok. Unfortunately I don't think that won't work in my flow. But thanks